# additional axis in box plot in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, boxplot, ggpubr

I am having the data below:

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "ID Group Value time
A1 A 21 10
A2 A 79 20
A3 A 32 30
B1 B 105 40
B2 B 44 50
B3 B 58 60
C1 C 32 70
C2 C 66 80
C3 C 143 90", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)
```

With the data, I plot a box plot using `ggboxplot` function:

```
library(ggpubr)

ggboxplot(data=df1,x="Group",y="Value",add = "jitter",short.panel.labs = FALSE)
```

and my plot is like:
[image]

Now I would like to add an additional axis on the top of the plot, putting the "dots" in the plot to be re-arranged based on the `time` column in `df1`, what I supposed to do is like:

[image]

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't rely on `ggboxplot()`, there's a solution with base plot.

```
boxplot(Value ~ Group, df1, xlim=c(.4, 3.5),
        xlab="Group", ylab="Value")
points(df1$time/100*3.5, df1$Value, pch=16)
axis(3, seq(0, 3.5, length.out=11), 0:10*10)
mtext("time", 3, 3)
```

***Explanation***

We first make a normal boxplot and slightly expand the y-axis with `xlim()` to the left (which otherwise starts at 0.5). Then we overlay the plot with `points()` by scaling the secondary x-axis (`"time"`) to the [0, 3.5] range of the x-axis of the boxplot. Then we add the axis and label it and finally we add a label for the secondary x-axis with `mtext()`.

***Result***

[image]

***Data***

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "B1", "B2", "B3", "C1", 
"C2", "C3"), Group = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", 
"C"), Value = c(21L, 79L, 32L, 105L, 44L, 58L, 32L, 66L, 143L
), time = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 60L, 70L, 80L, 90L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, by the way, do you have any suggestion about the grid of two plots, maybe I can plot it better with setting the grids

Comment: What exactly do you mean by grids?

Comment: I mean if I can know the exact position of the plot, I can adjust the "dots" position better

Comment: Ahaa. Yes, `boxplot()` has this nice feature also giving this kind of grid. Just do `g <- boxplot(.)` and it'll give you both a plot and the grid saved in `g`. Ok?